# android drawable border remove bottom line

Tags: android, drawable

Here is border xml
And I want to remove bottom, how to achieve it?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DECF7E" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try  below code and check if it gives desired result? It basically creates one background shape and and another shape in front of it. Background shape is just not including padding for bottom

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners
                    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
                <solid android:color="#DECF7E" />
                <padding android:top="1dp" />
                <padding android:left="1dp" />
                <padding android:right="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners
                   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                   android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Yes it works, and I add   <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> to second <item> to avoid some rectangle shadow on top corners.

Comment: @GHHyeah right, thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer accordingly.